# Google, Twitter APIs and a new IP Address

Tags: api, twitter, google-api, server, ip

I recently moved servers and changed IP addresses as a result, simply because it was easier at the time, but now my application refuses to authenticate with Google and Twitter's API mechanisms. I /think/ it might be IP address related, because regenerating the key for Microsoft's API seemed to do the trick but the other two were no go. It's been a few days now and I  was hoping it would  be a DNS propagation issue, but it seems not to be. Are there any solutions to this? The domain name has remained the same, only the IP address has changed. I've changed few other settings in the meantime and even restored from an old backup.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the problem I had was related to not having the Curl module activated for PHP. It was installed and everything, just not activated >.<